# right alignment of hboxes inside \vbox

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, box

I would like to produce a layout as follows:

```
|                                                   |
|first text ...left              first text ...right|
|second text ... left           second text... right|
|                                                   |
```

The four text snippets are essentially arguments that should be filled in by an end user, but the assumption that the text will fit in one line can be safely made.

i.e. I want to some stacked lines on the left of the page and some stacked lines on the right of the page. They should be left / right aligned correspondingly.

Now, judging from what I know about horizontal and vertical modes, I would say that I want to produce one `\hbox` that will contain two `\vbox`es (and some glue), and we can place the several lines as `\hbox`es into each vbox on the left and the right.

This, however, also aligns both text lines on the right margin left (to the width of the longer one). Fitting glue inside `\hbox{first text... right}` etc also does not help, since this glue does not stretch at all when actually producing the `\hbox`.

I am asking this slightly more specific question since I would like a more general solution: In other cases I might not know that the left consists of two lines that I can control, it just might be some arbitrary vbox. I might still want to be able to stack some text on separate lines on the right and then align the baseline of the bottom line of the stacked text with the baseline of the vbox on the left.

I would like a mode to tell the `vbox` that all `hbox`es that it contains will be right-aligned. How can I achieve that semantically?

In case this is relevant for answers (I do not think so): All of this takes place in a `mdframed` box (from typesetting point this should be equivalent to a `minipage`, but I am not sure)

Although I have no experience with `l3box`, an expl solution would also be very nice, but I don't know if there is actually benefits from this.

---

What I have tried so far:

- A hacky solution: tried to use the `\hbox to <dimen> {first text... right0}` syntax so that the glue will be stretched correspondingly. Since I do not know what of the two boxes is the wider one, I ended up with this quite messy code:

```
\setbox0=\hbox{first text ...right}
\setbox1=\hbox{second text ...right}
\ifnum \wd0 > \wd1 \setbox2=\hbox{first text ...right} \else \setbox2=\hbox{second text ...right} \fi
\leavevmode \vbox{\hbox{first text ...left}\hbox{second text ...left}} \hfill \vbox{\hbox to \wd2{\hfil first text ...right}\hbox to \wd2{\hfil second text ...right}}
```

This does the job but feels really ugly.

- I tried this using tabulars, i.e.

```
\begin{tabular}{l}
  first text \\
  second text
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{r}
  first text right \\
  second text right
\end{tabular}
```

but this messes up spacing around the tabulars on the left and right and I do not know how to prevent that, so unfortunately, this is not an option for me.

Comment: you just want `@{}l@{}` and `@{}r@{}` to remove the tabular padding, but the whole question is rather strange from the title and first 3/4 of the questio i assumed it was a plain tex question as neither `\hbox` nor `\vbox` should appear in a latex document (and the examples given were incompatible with latex color support for example) but then at the end you say you need this in a latex context?

Comment: what would you use in a LaTeX context instead of hbox and vbox? Also I must admit that unfortunately, I don't know too much about the LaTeX color support.

Comment: Do not use `\setbox0=\hbox{first text ...right}` in LaTeX, because color settings, for example, can leak out of the box to unexpected places. LaTeX provides `\savebox`, `\sbox` and environment `lrbox`. Example: `\sbox{0}{first text ...right}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard latex solution here would be

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}@{}l}
  first text \\
  second text
\end{tabular}%
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}r@{}}
  first text right \\
  second text right
\end{tabular}
```

Note `[t]` to top align, `@{}` to remove the `\tabcolsep` padding around the columns and `%` to remove the word-space between the tables. Depending where this is used, you may also need `\noindent` before the first `tabular` to prevent paragraph indentation.

Answer (score 2):

Plain TeX solution:

```
\noindent X\dotfill X

\hbox to \hsize{first text\hfil first text right}
\hbox to \hsize{second text\hfil second text right}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\bye
```

[image]

LaTeX solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\pairedtext}[2]{%
  \par\noindent
  \makebox[\textwidth][s]{#1\hfil #2}%
  \par
}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\pairedtext{first text}{first text right}
\pairedtext{second text}{second text right}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```

Or, if this is part of a title page with generous spacing above and below:

```
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lr@{}}
first text & first text right \\
second text & second text right
\end{tabular*}
```